# regex for PropertyName e.g. HelloWorld2HowAreYou would get Hello HelloWorld2 HelloWorld2How 

Tags: c#, regex

I need a regex for PropertyName e.g. `HelloWorld2HowAreYou` would get:

```
 Hello HelloWorld2 HelloWorld2How etc.
```

I want to use it in C#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[A-Z][a-z0-9]+` would give you all words that start with capital letter. You can write code to concat them one by one to get the complete set of words.

For example matching `[A-Z][a-z0-9]+` against `HelloWorld2HowAreYou` with global flag set, you will get the following matches.

```
Hello
World2
How
Are
You
```

Just iterate through the matches and concat them to form the words.

---

Port this to `C#`

```
var s = "HelloWorld2HowAreYou";
var r = /[A-Z][a-z0-9]+/g;
var m;
var matches = [];
while((m = r.exec(s)) != null)
  matches.push(m[0]);
var o = "";
for(var i = 0; i < matches.length; i++)
{
  o += matches[i]
  console.log(o + "\n");
}
```

Comment: hey @Armaghosh You've been helping me a lot with action script, thank you very much ;)

Answer (score 1):

I think something like this is what you want:

```
var s = "HelloWorld2HowAreYou";
Regex r = new Regex("(?=[A-Z]|$)(?<=(.+))");

foreach (Match m in r.Matches(s)) {
   Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[1]);
}
```

The output is ([as seen on ideone.com](http://ideone.com/MBDSw)):

```
Hello
HelloWorld2
HelloWorld2How
HelloWorld2HowAre
HelloWorld2HowAreYou
```

---

#### How it works

The regex is based on two assertions:

- `(?=[A-Z]|$)` matches positions just before an uppercase, and at the end of the string
- `(?<=(.+))` is a capturing lookbehind for `.+` behind the current position into group 1

Essentially, the regex translates to:

- "Everywhere just before an uppercase, or at the end of the string"...
- "grab everything behind you if it's not an empty string"